# Strange "Resource leak: stream is never closed" with try-with-resources if Exception is thrown in a loop

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, compiler-warnings, try-with-resources

Why is Eclipse giving a strange *"Resource leak: zin is never closed"* warning for the following code even though I use `try-with-resources`:

```
Path file = Paths.get("file.zip");
// Resource leak warning!
try (ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(Files.newInputStream(file))) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if (Math.random() < 0.5)
            throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If I modify "anything" on the code, the warning goes away. Below I list 3 modified versions which are all OK (no warnings).

---

**Mod #1:** If I remove the `for` loop from the `try` block, the warning goes away:

```
// This is OK (no warning)
try (ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(Files.newInputStream(file))) {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5)
        throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Mod #2:** Also no warning if I keep the `for` loop but I remove the wrapping `ZipInputStream`:

```
// This is OK (no warning)
try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file))) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if (Math.random() < 0.5)
            throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Mod #3:** If I create the `InputStream` outside the `try-with-resources`, also no warning:

```
// This is also OK (no warning)
InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file); // I declare to throw IOException
try (ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(in)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if (Math.random() < 0.5)
            throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I use Eclipse Kepler (4.3.1) but also the same result with Kepler SR2 (4.3.2).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug in Eclipse: *[[compiler][resource] Bad resource leak problem on return inside while loop (resource passed on in finally block](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371614)*.

I just got bit by this myself, and have added my vote on the tracker.

**Update:** The above bug has been resolved in 4.5 M7.  This will be included in the final release of Eclipse 4.5 ("Mars") - which looks on track to be released 2015-06-24.

Comment: I was assuming something like that, but good to have confirmation on that I don't have to change my logic or style, it's just a bug in the IDE.