# "Resource never closed" in try-with-resources when method chaining

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, compiler-warnings, try-with-resources

```
try(InputStream in = url.openStream(); Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A")) {

} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The line

> new Scanner(in)

gives the warning:

```
Resource leak: <unassigned Closeable> value' is never closed
```

*It goes away if I remove `useDelimiter(String)`.*

`useDelimiter(String)` does not return a new instance (it returns `this`), so why am I getting this warning? Is it a bug?

I am using Eclipse 4.4. My question is not relevant to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294612/2398375), where a warning occurs due to a different situation

Comment: It may be problem with eclipse. Check this link : http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-avoiding_resource_leaks.htm. Same type of question is unanswered in SE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459568/eclipse-inconsistencies-resource-leak-unassigned-closeable-value-is-never

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, this looks like a bug in the leak checker. I would recommend filing a bug report. Initial googling seems to indicate that one doesn't already exist.

Although I guess you could claim that it is not possible to solve this problem properly. The issue is that it would be difficult to statically prove that useDelimiter returns this without a lot of special casing.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ has this flaw too. For me, it doesn't seem hard at all for the resource checker to figure out that useDelimiter() returns *this*. So I think this could be a quick win if fixed in IntelliJ and/or Eclipse :)